# Generate JSON file from file names and their content

Tags: python, json, linux

I'm new to python, and couldn't find a close enough answer to make me figure it out. I'm trying generate a single json file that contains current directory file names that end with a .txt extension as nodes, and the contents of those files as a list inside the file name's node.

for example:

node1.txt contains

```
foo
bar
```

and node2.txt contains

```
test1
test2
```

the output should look like:

```json
{
  "node1": [
     "foo",
     "bar"
   ],
   "node2": [
     "test1",
     "test2"
   ]
}
```

Comment: You should provide your best attempt(s), so we can see where you are actually stuck.

Comment: As a starting point I suggest you take a look at the glob module https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: @AndyKnight. I suggest instead the OP takes a look to [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: you need to learn 1) how to read a file. 2) how to generate json. 3) how to write to a file. These are what you should be asking yourself. Rather than asking for an end to end solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pathlib` and `json` modules and a simple loop...

```
import pathlib
import json

data = {}
for node in pathlib.Path('.').glob('node*.txt'):
    with open(node, 'r') as fp:
        data[node.stem] = [line.strip() for line in fp.readlines()]

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "node1": [
        "foo",
        "bar"
    ],
    "node2": [
        "test1",
        "test2"
    ]
}
```